# A program detecting whether it's running in a virtual machine

Tags: operating-systems

I heard hypervisors try to make this undetectable to the client .A good hypervisor will have zero latency and be transparent.

*Can a program detect whether it's running in a virtual machine by trying to create a VM underneath it (and failing)?*

Or is a VM more like a subroutine call, where the context is passed to it and unquestioned?

Or do hypervisors forbid VM nesting?

Or what?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading about "VM detection", e.g., https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1686, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39533/781723.  There is lots written on this topic.

Comment: That's all about Linux, and it describes 2 ways: look at the graphics driver, and the method I suggested. That's it?